# Is it possible to catch the value of any field in a table? and once catched, can it be inserted into another table? SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to catch a field from a table (User), for example the Id, to be inserted in another table.

Example:

```
DECLARE @tempUSERNAME NVARCHAR(1000) = 'HERE USERNAME'
DECLARE @tempUSERID NVARCHAR(1000) = 'HERE USERID'

SELECT Id, UserName FROM Users WHERE UserName = @tempUSERNAME;
GO

INSERT INTO Person(Id, FirstName, LastName, UserId) VALUES
(newid(), 'FIRST NAME', 'LAST NAME', @tempUSERID);
GO
```

And the error that I have is:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@tempUSERNAME".
```

But is it possible, or could I catch it with a subquery?

Comment: GO is a batch delimiter. All statements up to the GO are sent to SQL Server, processed, and the results received by SSMS. Only then is the next batch - the statements up to the next GO - sent. Variables (@Something) are only in scope for the batch in which they are declared. In other words, a GO makes a variable stop working. Hence your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can INSERT directly from a SELECT if you don't need to reference the variables elsewhere

```
INSERT INTO Person
  (Id, FirstName, LastName, UserId)
SELECT
  newid(), 'FIRST NAME', 'LAST NAME', u.id
FROM Users as u
WHERE UserName = 'HERE USERNAME';
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`GO` utility statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) marks the end of a batch of T-SQL statements.

The variables you declared at the top of the first batch go out of scope after the first `GO` statement.  So you can't use them anymore in the 2nd batch (where the `INSERT` statement is).

To solve that, just remove the `GO` statement.

As far as your other goal, you can store the `Id` that goes with that `UserName` by changing your `SELECT` statement to this:

```
SELECT @tempUSERID = Id
FROM Users 
WHERE UserName = @tempUSERNAME;
```

Notice the variable assignment in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @vic sorry, I don't understand your question.